# How dropout works in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

how dropout works for 3d input.
for example, for `tf.nn.dropout(x, 0.1)`
if size of x is 3 dimensional of size 2 * 10 * 10

then is dropout applied channel-wise means in each channel it ignores randomly 10 values 
(so that in this example for the first channel ignores randomly 10 and for 2nd channel ignores randomly 10) 
or it 
applies on whole input means it ignores randomly 20 values from whole 2 * 10 * 10 features?

Answer (score 0):

Dropout is nothing but regularization but we only use few features or neurons in a layer instead of regularization of whole layer. Dropout can be applied for each layer if necessary. We have to worry about one parameter mainly when dealing with dropout i.e., rate. And also dropout is used for overfitting or high variance. Here's how it works:

Let consider a single neuron neural network with only 5 features which are given to a single neuron. Now the adding of dropout in this example is because the neuron can't rely on any single feature so, when dropout applied to this input then it makes few inputs according to rate given and it selects randomly few features and eliminate at that particular iteration. So, for every iteration dropout will randomly eliminate features this makes the neuron not to rely on any one feature.

Now let us consider deep neural network with 5 layers with 3 features hidden units:[7, 7, 3, 2, 1] where last layer is the output layer. Now in this example we can add dropout for every layer but here's how it varies. When applied to first layer which has 7 units, we use rate = 0.3 which means we have to drop 30% of units from 7 units randomly. For next layer which has 7 units, we add dropout rate = 0.5 because here previous layer 7 units and this layer 7 units which make this layer to overfit the data so, we are making 50% of units drop. For third layer we should decrease rate because hidden layers for third layer is 7 and fourth layer is 3 which means there are few connection only. And now with next layers we don't need to apply dropout because it only has few hidden units.
Now we can apply dropout for input layer but it is not done often. If may be done then the rate to drop will be almost 0.1 and less than that.

This is all about dropout. I have done a deep learning course on coursera so sharing this information from that knowledge.

Comment: Thank you but my question is about in 3d input how it drops the values like as I mentioned in the example.

Comment: As I mentioned when given a 3D input let us take your case 10x10x2 . Now the number of features is 300. Now when applied dropout with some rate all it does is randomly select and drop them. It does matter you have 3D input because all we know is features.  So, dropout will randomly select and drop them.